# Random LocalStorage Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a group of divs called "oponente", and if the user do not click on one of them in five seconds the script will choose one randomly. What I dont know how to do is to keep in LocalStorage which div the script had choose. Here is my script, I dont know what to write on 'key name' and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".oponente").addClass("gray");
    var elements = $(".oponente");
    var elementCount = elements.size();
    var elementsToShow = 1;
    var alreadyChoosen = ",";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < elementsToShow) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
        if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            setTimeout(function () {
                elements.eq(rand).window.localStorage.setItem('key name', 'key name');
            }, 5000);
            ++i;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store index of selected one. Then you can get child from the parent with that index number clearly.

Let me simulate

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".oponente").addClass("gray");
    var elements = $(".oponente");
    var elementCount = elements.size();
    var elementsToShow = 1;
    var alreadyChoosen = ",";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < elementsToShow) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
        if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            setTimeout(function () {
                localStorage.setItem('indexOfSelected', selectedDiv.index());
            }, 5000);
            ++i;
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can get the selected div with

```
var indexOfSelected = localStorage.getItem('indexOfSelected');
myDiv = parentDiv.children(":eq("+indexOfSelected+")")
```

All you need to init a `selectedDiv` then a `parentDiv` which is parent of the `selectedDiv`.